# Recursive Typedef in C++

Tags: c++, boost, vector, variant

I want to write a typedefinition in c++, but do not know if something I want to implement is legal. Let's say I want to do a typedef of a vector of boost variant types, which point to an int, or another vector of the same type. So, would this be legal and would the compiler complain?

```
typedef std::vector<boost::variant<int *, boost::variant<int *, IntBranch*>> IntBranch;
```

Comment: If the compiler complains, you'll know when you try and it gives you an error.

Comment: The compiler won't complain, but this won't do what you want I'm afraid

Comment: @AndyProwl, It won't give an error for not having seen `IntBranch` yet? Something like [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/htaz%240)?

Comment: @chris: Right, sorry. I haven't scrolled completely to the right. My bad, I suck, etc :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `boost::make_recursive_variant` for that purpose:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
   int*, 
   std::vector< boost::recursive_variant_ >
>::type IntBranch;
```

And this is how you would use it:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
       int*, 
       std::vector< boost::recursive_variant_ >
    >::type IntBranch;

    int x = 42;
    IntBranch ib = &x;

    std::vector<IntBranch> v;
    v.push_back(ib);

    IntBranch ib2 = v;

    // ...
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243644).

Comment: @chris: Actually `recursive_wrapper` allows even more control, but in this case `make_recursive_variant` should be enough

Comment: Thank you very much for this code posting. Unfortunately, I am having some issues understanding how to traverse through this tree. Let's say I have IntBranch with integers filled up to position i, and then at position i there is another vector. How would I traverse a tree like this by inputting some kind of position vector?

Comment: @user1876508: You could do it more or less the way I am showing in the live example linked in the answer. Or you could define a visitor inheriting from `boost::static_visitor`. The Boost.Variant documentation explains this in detail

Comment: I don't see how to do this, and the documentation is not helping me. I have moved this question over here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907187/how-to-traverse-a-recursive-variant-vector-using-boost-c . Thank you taking the time so far to help me. Unfortunately I just dove into the C++ world about a month ago, and getting used to reading the boost documentation has proved to be difficult for me.