# How to traverse a recursive variant vector using Boost C++

Tags: c++, search, boost, tree

I want to build a vector tree constructed as follows

```
struct myStruct {
    int a;
    string b;
};

typedef boost::make_recursive_variant<
      myStruct *
    , std::vector< boost::recursive_variant_ >
    >::type myStruct_tree;
```

If I append a multiple vectors, and vectors in those vectors, how would I traverse the tree using some kind of position vector

```
vector<int>
```

Which locates the objects position in each vector/subvector defined in the vector pointer tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, so please clarify if I get something wrong. I'm assuming the vector is a path, with each element giving the index of the element to move to. With that in mind, I'd try something like this:

```
myStruct_tree t = ...;

myStruct_tree* tit = &t;
for(iterator pit=path.begin(); pit!=path.end(); ++pit)
{
    // retrieve branches at current position
    vector<myStruct_tree>& vec = get<2>(*tit);

    // get next position in tree, will throw on bad index
    tit = &vec.at(*pit);
}
assert(tit);

// retrieve the leaf at the final position
myStruct* res = get<1>(*tit);
```

Notes:

- Using an unsigned integer for the indices would be a bit more natural to me.
- vector::at() throws an exception on out-of-range.
- I haven't looked up the exact syntax of how to get an element of the variant. With the version `get<1>(*tit);` I used above, I meant the one that retrieves the first element (i.e. the myStruct pointer). Further, it should be the one that returns a reference or throws in order to handle errors.
- Consider replacing the range-checking with your own code in order to provide better diagnostics. I didn't do it to keep the structure of the algorithm clear.